# How can i use grouped_select group_method with a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, scope, simple-form

I try to use grouped_selects group_method with a custom scope. A user can see only projects and tasks he belongs to.

This is working, i got all my Project with Tasks to select:

```
# using simple_form
<%= f.input :project_id, :as => :grouped_select,
            :collection => Project.my_scope(current_user),
            :group_method => :tasks %>
```

This is not working. I try to get the tasks from my_scope.

```
# using simple_form
<%= f.input :project_id, :as => :grouped_select,
            :collection => Project.my_scope(current_user),
            :group_method => Task.my_scope(current_user) %>
```

**UPDATE**

I also tried this with rails default helper and this seems to work:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:project_id,
                                Project.my_scope(current_user),
                                :"tasks.my_scope(#{current_user.id})",
                                :name, :id, :name) %>
```

Is this a common practise or are there other ways to achieve my needs?

Answer (score 3):

It's not working because `:group_method` specifies what method to call, to group the selects by what it returns

So scope cannot be used there. What result do you want to achieve? Probably you could limit your collection - if you want to display only projects with tasks for current_user (just assumed)
Then you can do smth like this

```
# using simple_form
<%= f.input :project_id, :as => :grouped_select,
            :collection => Project.my_scope(current_user).joins(:tasks).where(:assigned_to => current_user),
            :group_method => :task %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A user can belong to a project, but can only see tasks the user belongs to. The limiting projects does not achieve what i need.